# Run jQuery script on multiple elements of the same type with different content (sizes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to run a small jQuery script to center my images according to the text block next to them.

I am using [foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which is why I am having to using a jQuery script to override the CSS instead of `vertical-align: middle` etc...

The script is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    var row = $('.row').css("height");

    var center = $('.center');
    center.height(row);

    var centered = $('.centered');
    var imgSize = parseInt(centered.css("height")) / 2;
    var rowInt = parseInt(row);
    var top = (rowInt / 2) - imgSize;
    centered.css({"margin-top" : top + 'px'});

});
```

Basically what this does is set the column that holds the image to the same height as the parent row, then it sets the `margin-top` of the image to be half the size of the column **minus** half the size of the image.

It works for the first column, but then applies the same height/margin to the remaining rows.

To see the full thing in action please see this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bL4bhy1a/1/)** (**jsFiddle results window will have to be wide enough for image to be left/right of text, if too small image will just move to above/below text**).

What I need is the script to run on each individual row, and be ready to handle more rows if they should come later on.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this for *each* row rather than using a single calculation. So loop through the rows, and work *within* each row:

```
$(function(){
    $('.row').each(function() {
        var thisRow = $(this);
        var rowHeight = thisRow.css("height");

        var center = thisRow.find('.center');
        center.height(rowHeight);

        var centered = thisRow.find('.centered');
        var imgSize = parseInt(centered.css("height")) / 2;
        var rowInt = parseInt(rowHeight);
        var top = (rowInt / 2) - imgSize;
        centered.css({"margin-top" : top + 'px'});
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bL4bhy1a/2/) *(I also changed the name of the `row` variable to `rowHeight` to make it better reflect what it actually contained)*

One of the key things about jQuery's getter/setter functions (`css`, `html`, `attr`, `val`, and so on) is that they're *assymetrical*: When you're *setting* a value, they set on all elements in the jQuery set, but when you're *getting* a value, they get it only from the *first* element in the set. So your code doing `$('.row').height()` was getting the height of the *first* row, and then your code applying that (`center.height(row)`, `centered.css({"margin-top": top + 'px'})`) was applying the values to *all* `.center` and `.centered` elements.

Comment: Thank you so much, your a life saver and thank you for the nice explanation :). Will accept as soon as it lets me!